# Feeding a List of Lists into a function

Tags: python

I have a multi-dimensional array that I am trying to feed into `difflib.get_close_matches()`.

My array looks like this: `array[(ORIGINAL, FILTERED)]`. `ORIGINAL` is a string, and `FILTERED` is the `ORIGINAL` string with common words filtered out.

I currently have a new array being created with only the `FILTERED` words being fed into `difflib.get_close_matches()`. I then try to match the result from `difflib` to the `array[(ORIGINAL, FILTERED)]`. My problem is that often times I have two or more `FILTERED` words that are equivalent and therefore they can't be matched using this method.

Is there a way where I can feed the entire `array[(ORIGINAL,FILTERED)]` into `difflib`, but have it only look at the `FILTERED` part (while still returning the `[(ORIGINAL,FILTERED)]`?)

Thanks in advance!

```
import  time
import  csv
import  difflib
import  sys
import  os.path
import  datetime

### Filters out common  words   in  an  attempt to  get better      results ###
def ignoredWords (word):
    filtered = word.lower()
    #Common Full Words
## Majority of filters were edited out
    #Common Abbreviations
    if "univ" in filtered:
        filtered = filtered.replace("univ","")
    #Special Characters
    if "  " in filtered: #Two White Spaces
        filtered = filtered.replace("  "," ")
    if "-" in filtered:
        filtered = filtered.replace("-"," ")
    if "\'" in filtered:
        filtered = filtered.replace("\'"," ")
    if " & " in filtered:
        filtered = filtered.replace(" &","")
    if "(\"" in filtered:
        filtered = filtered.replace("(\"","")
    if "\")" in filtered:
        filtered = filtered.replace("\")","")
    if "\t" in filtered:
        filtered = filtered.replace("\t"," ")
    return  filtered

### Takes in a list, then outputs a 2D list. array[Original, Filtered] ###
### For XXX: array[Original, Filtered, Account Number, Code] ###
def create2DArray (list):
    array = []
    for item in list:
        clean = ignoredWords(item[2])
        entry = (item[2].lower(), clean, item[0],item[1])
        array.append(entry)
    return array

def main(argv):
    if(len(argv) < 3):
        print "Not enough parameters. Please enter two file names"
        sys.exit(2)
    elif (not os.path.isfile(argv[1])):
        print "%s is not found" %(argv[1])
        sys.exit(2)
    elif (not os.path.isfile(argv[2])):
        print "%s is not found" %(argv[2])
        sys.exit(2)
    #Recode File ----- Not yet implemented
#       if(len(argv) == 4):
#       if(not os.path.isfile(argv[3])):
#           print "%s is not found" %(argv[3])
#           sys.exit(2)
#           
#       recode = open(argv[1], 'r')
#       try:
#           setRecode = c.readlines()
#       finally:
#           recode.close()
#           setRecode.sort()
#           print setRecode[0]
    #Measure execution time
    t0 = time.time()

    cReader = csv.reader(open(argv[1], 'rb'), delimiter='|')
    try:
        setC = []
        for row in cReader:
            setC.append(row)
    finally:
        setC.sort()

    aReader = csv.reader(open(argv[2], 'rb'), delimiter='|')
    try:
        setA = []
        for row in aReader:
            setA.append(row)
    finally:
        setA.sort()

    #Put Set A and Set C into their own 2 dimmensional arrays.array[Original Word]    [Cleaned Up Word]
    arrayC = create2DArray(setC)
    arrayA = create2DArray(setA)

    #Create clean list versions for use with difflib
    cleanListC = []
    for item in arrayC:
        cleanListC.append(item[1])

    cleanListA = []
    for item in arrayA:
        cleanListA.append(item[1])

    ############OUTPUT FILENAME############
    fMatch75 = open("Match75.csv", 'w')
    Match75 = csv.writer(fMatch75, dialect='excel')
    try:
        header = "Fuzzy Matching Report. Generated: "
        header += str(datetime.date.today())
        Match75.writerow([header])
        Match75.writerow(['C','A','C Cleaned','A Cleaned','C Account', 'C Group','A Account', 'A Group', 'Filtered Ratio %','Unfiltered Ratio %','Average Ratio %'])
        for item in cleanListC:
            match = difflib.get_close_matches(item,cleanListA,1,0.75)
            
            if len(match) > 0:
                filteredratio = difflib.SequenceMatcher(None,item,match[0]).ratio()
                strfilteredratio = '%.2f' % (filteredratio*100)
                found = 0
                for group in arrayA:
                    if match[0] == group[1]:
                        origA = group[0]
                        acode = group[3]
                        aaccount = group[2]
                        found = found + 1
                for group in arrayC:
                    if item == group[1]:
                        origC = group[0]
                        ccode = group[3]
                        caccount = group[2]
                        found = found + 2
                if found == 3:
                    unfilteredratio = difflib.SequenceMatcher(None,origC,origA).ratio()
                    strunfilteredratio = '%.2f' % (unfilteredratio*100)
                    averageratio = (filteredratio+unfilteredratio)/2
                    straverageratio = '%.2f' % (averageratio*100)
                    
                    row = [origC.rstrip(),origA.rstrip(),item.rstrip(),match[0].rstrip(),caccount,ccode,aaccount,acode,strfilteredratio,strunfilteredratio,straverageratio]
                    Match75.writerow(row)
                #These Else Ifs are for debugging. If NULL is found anywhere in the CSV, then an error has occurred
                elif found == 2:
                    row = [origC.rstrip(),"NULL",item.rstrip(),match[0].rstrip(),caccount,ccode,"NULL","NULL",strfilteredratio,"NULL","NULL"]
                    Match75.writerow(row)
                elif found == 1:
                    row = ["NULL",origA.rstrip(),item.rstrip(),match[0].rstrip(),"NULL","NULL",aaccount,acode,strfilteredratio,"NULL","NULL"]
                    Match75.writerow(row)
            else:
                    row = ["NULL","NULL",item.rstrip(),match[0].rstrip(),"NULL","NULL","NULL","NULL",strfilteredratio,"NULL","NULL"]
                    Match75.writerow(row)
                
    finally:
        Match75.writerow(["A Proprietary and Confidential. Do Not Distribute"])
        fMatch75.close()

    print (time.time()-t0,"seconds")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(argv=sys.argv)
```

**What I am trying to achieve:**

1. Read input files
2. Filter out common words from names so that the fuzzy matching ('difflib.get_close_matches()') will return more accurate results
3. Compare names from FileA to names in FileB to find which one is most likely a match.
4. Print out the original (un-filtered) names and the match percentage.

**Why this is difficult**

The naming conventions used in the two input files vary significantly. Some of the names are partially abbreviated (EX: File A: Acme Company; File B: Acme Co). Since the naming conventions aren't consistent, I can't do 'FileA.intersect(FileB)' which would have been the ideal way.

**Where the modification should occur**

```
for item in cleanListC:
    match = difflib.get_close_matches(item,cleanListA,1,0.75)
```

CleanListA is created by:

```
cleanListA = []
    for item in arrayA:
        cleanListA.append(item[1])
```

Thus losing the `(ORIGINAL,FILTERED)` pairing.

**End Goal**

I would like to feed arrayA into `difflib.get_close_matches()` instead of cleanListA to preserve the `(ORIGINAL,FILTERED)` pairing. `difflib.get_close_matches()` would only look at the 'FILTERED' part of the pairing when determining the close matches, but return the entire pairing.

Comment: @MikeKusold What do you mean with name 'array' ? In Python, I understand that: (http://docs.python.org/library/array.html#module-array)

Comment: I used array[ORIGINAL, FILTERED] as a means to describe my variable clearly. You can just as easily substitute words[(Original,Filtered)].

Comment: We need you to be more specific, please. Is it an `array.array` object?  Or is it actually a `list`? Or by "multi-dimensional array" do you actually mean a `dict`? These are all distinct in Python. Additionally, please show us what you've tried (with code!). The more detail the better!!

Comment: I'm fairly new to Python so I don't have all the terminology quite down. I believe it is a list, but what do you call a list in a list? I will post some code later today. Unfortunately this is used to generate confidential information for my employer so it will take me some time to edit the code to be general enough to share.

Comment: @MikeKusold A list in a list is a sub-list (sub-list being an english expression, not a term in the Python's terminology). A list of lists is a list of lists, there is no pythonic term to call it another way; some call a list of lists a _matrix_ but they are wrong.

Comment: I posted the code. Please excuse the variables, I had to abbreviate some down to one letter.

Comment: @MikeKusold: It might be easier if you described what you're trying to achieve with what inputs, I'm getting the feeling that there's a simpler approach.

Comment: @MikeKusold: Could you also state in the code where you want to make a modification, it should be easier to understand (also providing only relevant/smaller code is better for other to understand)

Comment: @MikeKusold: Definitely need to see some example data from the input files. I strongly suspect the code could be significantly simplified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're already using `SequenceMatcher` directly to get the match ratio, your most straightforward change would probably be to do the `get_close_matches` operation yourself.

Compare the source for get_close_matches() [e.g., http://svn.python.org/view/python/tags/r271/Lib/difflib.py?revision=86833&view=markup near line 737].  It returns a list of the *n* sequences with the highest ratios.  Since you want just the best match, you could keep track of the (ORIGINAL,FILTERED,ratio) where ratio is the highest so far, instead of the `heapq` the original method uses to track the *n* highest.

For example, in place of your main loop, something like:

```
seqm = difflib.SequenceMatcher()

for i in arrayC:
  origC, cleanC, caccount, ccode = i
  seqm.set_seq2(cleanC)

  bestRatio = 0

  for j in arrayA:
    origA, cleanA = j[:2]
    seqm.set_seq1(cleanA)

    if (seqm.real_quick_ratio() >= bestRatio and
        seqm.quick_ratio() >= bestRatio):
      r = seqm.ratio()
      if r >= bestRatio:
        bestRatio = r
        bestA = j

  if bestRatio >= 0.75: # the cutoff from the original get_close_matches() call
    origA, cleanA, aaccount, acode = bestA

    filteredratio = bestRatio
    strfilteredratio = '%.2f' % (filteredratio*100)

    seqm.set_seqs( origC, origA )
    unfilteredratio = seqm.ratio()
    strunfilteredratio = '%.2f' % (unfilteredratio*100)

    averageratio = (filteredratio+unfilteredratio)/2
    straverageratio = '%.2f' % (averageratio*100)

    row = [origC.rstrip(),origA.rstrip(),cleanC.rstrip(),cleanA.rstrip(),caccount,ccode,aaccount,acode,strfilteredratio,strunfilteredratio,straverageratio]
  else:
    row = ["NULL","NULL","NULL","NULL","NULL","NULL","NULL","NULL","0.00","NULL","NULL"]

  Match75.writerow(row)
```

Comment: I ended up going this route. I was hoping that there was a way to feed in the list such as list[1][i] or something, but this worked too.